# Bootstrap 4 landing layout components getting on top of another

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm relatively new with frontend so having a bit of problem in organizing a layout using bootstrap 4. I'm trying to build a banner for the landing page. I've attached the desired layout look please check it out. Below is my code which is all messing up the layout and coming on top of another.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 ml-auto">
            <h1 class="presentation-title">COMPANY NAME IN H1</h1>
            <div class="fog-low">
                <img src="assets/img/fog-low.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="fog-low right">
                <img src="assets/img/fog-low.png" alt="">
            </div>
        <h2 class="presentation-subtitle text-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </h2>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this example solve your issue?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/VwLKJvv

Comment: nope..the image is almost taking the whole page and the rest is overlapping it

Comment: Then what is your requirement?

Comment: The way you bordered the divs it's perfect. But under a same row for col-md-4 there should be the logo image having height of 60% and then the rest col-md-8 should have 2 rows heading and and para one after other with 50% height separated

Comment: Also keep in point that the container is also centered. so it can't take the full width of the screen

Answer (score 1):

You can fiddle around with this example and come up with idea on how to align and for logo set image size when u enter it inside the card view maybe `<img src="picname.jpg" alt="pic description" width="150" height="150">` to force resize so image don't break the view. Good Luck.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="row" style="margin:10px">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card" style="margin:10px">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Logo</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Can Add logo here</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="card" style="margin-bottom:10px">
          <div class="card-body">
            H1 HEADING
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            Small description in a paragraph.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```